# Compact Subsets of the Real Line have Finite Measures

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

I just want to check my reasoning on this one question:

Prove that if K is a compact subset of the real line, the measure of K is finite.

I am assuming this is simply because compact sets are closed and closed sets have finite outer measures. Is this correct or am I oversimplifying?

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph: $\mathbb R$ is a closed set, but it doesn't have a finite outer measure.

Comment: Any compact set is contained in $(-n,n)$ for some $n$.

Comment: Good points re R. Then is it the fact that it can be covered by a finite number of open sets?

Answer (score 4):

You’re not oversimplifying; you’re simplifying in the wrong direction. Compact sets are closed and bounded but it is the boundedness you need here. (The closedness happens to be irrelevant.) Boundedness means there is an $M$ such that $K\subset[-M,M]$. By the monotonicity of measures, $$\mu(K)\leq\mu([-M,M])=2M<\infty.$$

Comment: I haven't learned about monotonicity of measures in my course yet. Is there an alternate method?

Comment: Have you learned that measures are finitely additive for disjoint sets? It would follow immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Any point of $\Bbb R$ has an open neighbourhood of finite measure. (this is trivial as $\mu((x-1,x+1)) = 2$, e.g. but is a property that many measures ons paces have (it's called a *locally finite measure*).

A compact subset $K$ has a cover by such neighbourhoods thus a finite such cover  too. Then (finite)subadditivity and monotonicity of the measure do the rest and $\mu(K) < +\infty$.